# Stream system() output to Shiny front-end (continuously)

Tags: r, shell, shiny, stream, command-line-interface

How can I capture the output of an ongoing [`system()` operation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html) and stream it to the Shiny front-end in "real-time"?

`intern=T` captures the entire output in a character vector, but I would prefer to "listen" to the system output as it happens.

```
library(shiny) 
ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Stream the system output"),
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         actionButton("btn1",label = "Let's stream")
      ),
      mainPanel(
         textOutput("textstream_output")
      )
   )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rv <- reactiveValues("textstream"=c(""))
  output$textstream_output <- renderText({
    rv$textstream
  })
  observeEvent(input$btn1,{
  # problem: is evaluated after finish, not during operation  
    rv$textstream <- system("Rscript -e \"for(i in 1:5){ print(Sys.time()); Sys.sleep(1);  };\"",
                            intern = T)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When running the `system` command with `intern=F`, the R console continuously updates once per second. How can I establish that in Shiny, ideally without having to slice the `system` call into smaller chunks?

[image]

Possibly related:

- [Possible to show console messages (written with `message`) in a shiny ui?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474538/possible-to-show-console-messages-written-with-message-in-a-shiny-ui)
- [Extend time progress bar displays message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049090/extend-time-progress-bar-displays-message/33097449#33097449)
- [R Shiny: mirror R console outputs to Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35009691/r-shiny-mirror-r-console-outputs-to-shiny?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`reactiveTimer` provides one approach.  My guess is that your approach doesn't work because `observeEvent` only updates the reactive object once evaluation of the expression is completed.  Here's my approach. I create a script that I want to run in the background, `so_script.R`, and divert the output to `so_output.txt`. We wish to see the contents of `so_output.txt` while the script is running.

```
cat('sink(file = "so_output.txt")
  for (i in 1:10) {
    cat(format(Sys.time(), format = "%H:%M:%S"), "\n")
    Sys.sleep(1)
  }
  cat("*** EOF ***\n")
  sink()
', file = "so_script.R")
```

Here's the Shiny app:

```
library(shiny) 
ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Stream the system output"),
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         actionButton("btn_start",label = "Let's stream"),
         actionButton("btn_stop",label = "Stop")
      ),
      mainPanel(
         htmlOutput("textstream_output")
      )
   )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(textstream = c(""),
                       timer = reactiveTimer(1000),
                       started = FALSE)
  observeEvent(input$btn_start, { 
    rv$started <- TRUE
    system2("Rscript", "so_script.R", wait = FALSE)
  })
  observeEvent(input$btn_stop, { rv$started <- FALSE })
  observe({
    rv$timer()
    if (isolate(rv$started))
      rv$textstream <- paste(readLines("so_output.txt"), collapse = "<br/>")
  })
  output$textstream_output <- renderUI({
    HTML(rv$textstream)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Each time the timer fires, we read in the contents of `so_output.txt` if streaming has started.  Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I'm kinda digging up this old post but it had been helpful. I am currently wanting to implement something similar, but would like the reading from so_output.txt to stop without having to click a stop button. Do you think there is a way of detecting this ? Thanks in advance